# Why can we factor out $X$ in $E(E(XY∣X))$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Using the law of total expectation, $E(XY)=E(E(XY∣X))=E(XE(Y∣X))$

I understand the first equality is part of the definition, but why are we able to treat $X$ as a constant in the second equality and factor it out?

Comment: because $X$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable

Comment: I haven't learned about σ-algebra, would there be another way to explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $X$ is constant with respect to $X$.

The idea of $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ is the probability once $X$ is known, so the result is a function of $X$. Just like $\mathbb{E}(aY|X) = a\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ when $a$ is constant wrt $X$, so too $\mathbb{E}(XY|X) = X\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ since once $X$ is known, it is constant wrt itself.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding why X is a constant wrt X. Is it because when we calculate P(Y|X), we are generally finding P(Y|X=x) ? And in this case X is assigned a constant x?

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose exactly

Comment: That is not true for probability.  You should be talking about expectation.

Comment: @GrahamKemp you are right, changed

Answer (score 3):

Factoring out $X$ corresponds to the following manipulation in the case where $(X,Y)$ have a joint density:

$$
\begin{split}
E(XY)
 &= \iint xy f(x,y)dy dx \\
 &= \int_x \left(\int_y xy f(y\mid x)f(x)dy\right)dx \\
 &= \int_x x\left(\int_y y f(y\mid x)dy\right)f(x)dx
\end{split}
$$

Comment: although 100% true, this hardly would be very intuitive for the OP to understand. +1 still because someone else may benefit from this at some point.